# Bug when editing schema in Chrome

Tags: cme, 2013

When I try to create or edit a schema in Chrome, and the schema contains a category/keyword field, I am unable to save the schema. The console gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error is caused at coreresource_v7.1.0.66.6_.js, line 17.

I have installed all the hotfixes from sdltridionworld.com, but that did not help. The workaround is to use IE instead, that works fine. I haven't tried FF.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried it on Google Chrome 33.0.1750.154 and it worked fine. Chrome is updating now to version 34... and I get the same error.

So indeed, once more, Google Chrome managed to break compatibility... expect a hotfix soon once we figure out what broke.

Comment: Thanks Nuno! Don't you sometimes wish we were back in the day when IE6 was the only supported browser? ;-)

Comment: Not really :) but it is really challenging with Chrome. Mozilla is doing a much better job at not breaking with upgrades (I guess they are also doing less changes).

Comment: It does remind you a bit of those days though... I remember the browser team regularly being scrambled to intercept a new IE update.

Comment: Looks like Chrome removed support for DOM 2 and 3, and we still had some old code lying around. We're working on this. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341830

Comment: And now they have launched 35 beta...where all the fancy drop-downs lists on all the major sites are not working with mouse...looks like we need to go back to IE...after all Old is gold :)

Comment: Update: I also have a problem trying to cut and paste multiple items. The problem is: it does not work. I have to do it one by one. Could it be related?

Comment: Don't know - does it work with other browsers? I already updated my chrome to v34 so I can't really test it again with v33....

Answer (score 2):

All issues have been resolved in Chrome stable version 38. Please upgrade your browser and try again.