# Unable to save Schema after adding categories to schema Metadata

Tags: schema

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1. I am facing issue while creating and saving a new schema. When I add a category in the metadata of the schema then the schema is not getting saved and it keeps on  showing  **Saving Item...** state. But the schema got saved when I removed the category in metadata tab of the schema. Kindly suggest how to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of 

http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5230/bug-when-editing-schema-in-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Chrome version 34. That update removed functionality that is needed for the Tridion CME, and the use of Keywords in Schemas is one scenario where it breaks with JavaScript errors.

Until a hotfix is available, the workaround is to use a different browser. It's an unfortunate side effect of Chrome pushing out updates automatically and at the same time not guaranteeing backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. This issue got resolved when I used IE instead on Chrome(34).

Comment: Glad you are not blocked anymore. There is a hotfix currently being tested for this issue - I'll update the answer once it's officially released.

Comment: The hotfixes have been verified and are available through Customer Support (and on Tridion World soon). Ask for hotfix #87924. For customers using 2011 SP1 HR2, you'll want #87923.